# Speech input by Microsoft Bot Framework Composer

Tags: azure, bots, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I created a node bot with microsoft bot framework composer. It is a simple echo bot. And I published that also.

However, when I tried in emulator it has the input voice function. But, when I tried web chat there is no voice input option.

FIY: I have connected the bot with speech service

Enabled speech from the bot framework composer configuration.
Now can't do speech input in webchat..

Comment: Can you share you sample bot framework that you have deployed to azure portal?

Answer (score 0):

Web chat doesnt provide voice input. In order to use voice input, you need to enable direct line channel. Please follow this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/tutorial-voice-enable-your-bot-speech-sdk#register-the-direct-line-speech-channel